# how to run an Air class(ex:Demo.as) programatically

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a file Main.as which captures the video from camera and creates a stream.If i run this program manually then only it opens a window and captures video.Now i have to run this program automatically to open that window without any user interactin, when it used in application.How can i achieve that?
here is my Main.as file

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.net.Responder;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**0...
     * @author BECKER Christophe
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite {
        //
        public var vid : Video;
        public var cam : Camera;
        public var bt : Sprite;
        public var txt : TextField ;
        public var microphone : Microphone;
        private var connection:NetConnection;

        //public var boucle : int;
        //
        private var outStream:NetStream;
        public var nc : NetConnection;
        public var responder : Responder;
    //  public var flv_writer : FlvWriter;
        //
        private var inStream:NetStream;
        private var inVideo:Video;
        public function Main() {
        //  NetConnection.defaultObjectEncoding=flash.net.ObjectEncoding.AMF0;
            connection = new NetConnection();
            connection.client = { onBWDone: function():void{ trace("onBWDone") } };
        //  connection.objectEncoding = flash.net.ObjectEncoding.AMF0;
            connection.connect("rtmp://Ipaddress/TestApp"); 
            connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnected);

        }
            private function onConnected(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
        if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {

            if(Camera.names.length>0){
                cam = Camera.getCamera();
                cam.setMode(640, 480, 15);
            }
            if(Microphone.names.length>0)
                microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

            outStream = new NetStream(connection);
            outStream.attachCamera(cam);
            outStream.attachAudio(microphone);
            outStream.publish("DemoVideo1","live");

            //outStream.play("DemoVideo1");

            vid = new Video(300, 300);
            vid.attachCamera(cam);
            addChild(vid);



            inStream = new NetStream(connection);
            inStream.play("DemoVideo1");

            inVideo = new Video(250,250);
            inVideo.attachNetStream(inStream);

            addChild(inVideo);


                            }
        }

        private function metaDataHandler(meta : Object) : void {
            if (vid) {
                vid.width = meta.width;
                vid.height = meta.height;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on when you want the window to be displayed?

Comment: There is another java application from that a string will be received to an .as file.I implemented socket connection between the Actionscript file and java file. once it receives a particular string it has to call the above file and open the window to capture video. But the Server socket is implemented in Actionscript file so to accept connections from java clients, server has be started during the  application running means there should be call from java to run the .as file.It may be a process start